# How to create resizable widgets with tk/tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to enable the user to change the proportions of the layout by changing the position of the borders between widgets. Just in almost every modern GUI:

[image]
(Example from Matlab)

Comment: It's a shame those pictures are so small; the thing you're wanting to ask about is hard to spot in them…

Comment: @DonalFellows, you can see clearly that the ratio in the size of the 5 different windows has changed. And that is what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want is a paned widget

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_panedwindow.htm